# Disagreement between Python and MATLAB in calculating POSIX from datetime

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, datetime, posix

In MATLAB, I can easily convert a datetime object to posix:

```
start_time = datetime('2020-04-30 10:05:00');
start_time_unix = posixtime(start_time)
```

which returns:

```
start_time_unix = 1.588241100000000e+09.
```

In Python, I've created a similar datetime object and tried converting it to posix:

```
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np

time_string = '2020-04-30 10:05:00'
calendar, clock = time_string.split(' ')
year,month,day = [np.int(x) for x in calendar.split('-')]
hour,minute,second = [np.int(x) for x in clock.split(':')]
dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
ut = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
```

at which point,

```
ut = 1588262700.0
```

In case the hours and minutes are mixed up,

```
dt2 = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, minute, hour, second)
ut2 = time.mktime(dt2.timetuple())
```

returns

```
ut2 = 1588245000.0
```

Why am I seeing this discrepancy between MATLAB and Python? Also, is there a way to parse a date/time string and convert it to posix more efficiently?

Comment: For parsing, see [time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime).

Comment: Note there are exactly 6 hours between MATLAB and Python here. It's not very clear from the documentation of [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), but I believe by default it assumes local time, while [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.posixtime.html) assumes UTC by default. What's your timezone?

Comment: Currently, I'm in Mountain time. I did read the UTC assumption, but was hoping it was more robust than that. You're correct, 6 hours is the conversion between UTC and MST. I'll account for that assumption.

Comment: You may also specify the timezone. There is often some trial and error to deal correctly with datetime data, but I don't think it's a problem of robustness: one has to learn all the intricacies of measuring time (a huge task already), and the various implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, if you parse a date/time string that does not contain timezone information or UTC offset to a `datetime` object, the resulting object is naive, i.e. it does not know about any timezone, DST or UTC offset.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

> A naive object does not contain enough information to unambiguously
>   locate itself relative to other date/time objects. Whether a naive
>   object represents Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), local time, or
>   time in some other timezone is purely up to the program, just like it
>   is up to the program whether a particular number represents metres,
>   miles, or mass. Naive objects are easy to understand and to work with,
>   at the cost of ignoring some aspects of reality.

***Python will by default assume that a naive `datetime` object belongs in the timezone of your operating system!***

More from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow):

> **Warning:** Because naive datetime objects are treated by many datetime methods as local times, it is preferred to use aware
>   datetimes to represent times in UTC.

For the given example, you will need to specify timezone information to avoid ambiguities:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

# parse to datetime, in this case we don't need strptime since string is ISO8601 compatible
dtobj = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-04-30 10:05:00')
# naive, no tz info: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 30, 10, 5)

# add a timezone, for UTC, we can use timezone.utc from the datetime module:
dtobj = dtobj.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
# tz-aware: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 30, 10, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

# now we can obtain the posix timestamp:
posix = dtobj.timestamp()

print(posix)
# 1588241100.0
```

If you intend to work frequently with time series data in Python, have a look at the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package.